# Slack Interactive Messages not displayed in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-11, slack, slack-api

Even though Internet Explorer 11 is [supported by Slack](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201746897-Slack-apps-for-computers-phones-tablets#web-), the button messages generated by my bot cannot be displayed using Internet Explorer.

But I do receive the notification of a new message.

All the other browsers listed in the link above are able to display such messages.
Even the [message builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22Would%20you%20like%20to%20play%20a%20game%3F%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%22Choose%20a%20game%20to%20play%22%2C%22fallback%22%3A%22You%20are%20unable%20to%20choose%20a%20game%22%2C%22callback_id%22%3A%22wopr_game%22%2C%22color%22%3A%22%233AA3E3%22%2C%22attachment_type%22%3A%22default%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22game%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Chess%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22chess%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22game%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Falken's%20Maze%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22maze%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22game%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Thermonuclear%20War%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22danger%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22war%22%2C%22confirm%22%3A%7B%22title%22%3A%22Are%20you%20sure%3F%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Wouldn't%20you%20prefer%20a%20good%20game%20of%20chess%3F%22%2C%22ok_text%22%3A%22Yes%22%2C%22dismiss_text%22%3A%22No%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D) is not working for button messages in IE11.

If anyone can provide a solution it would be highly appreciated since my users will mainly use IE.

Comment: I just checked and its also not working for me on IE 11. Normal message and attachments send from a slash command work fine, but as soon as there are buttons included the message is not displayed anymore.

I would recommend contacting the Slack team and raising this issue. This is clearly a bug and I would assume the Slack guys are already working on it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it apparently involves a bug in the main vendor application and is therfore not directly related to programming.

Comment: After some try out it's the required field `callback_id` that makes the button not displayable. If you remove this field or set it to false or empty string the message will be visible but not usable.